# How to create the TableView dynamically as metioned below one screen shot in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio, android-tablayout

I have to create Table Layout dynamically in android. First one header for one row, second one two column for another row in Table Layout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKEyk.jpg

Comment: maybe you forget to attach the screenshot ?

Comment: i couldn't attach the screen shot, i don't know why

Comment: try uploading on imgur.com site and then sharing link here

Comment: Is there any rules for attach the screen like upvote

Comment: I did let see that

Comment: your screenshot is unrelated to question you are asking

Comment: okay, i saw it. question is too broad. have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: I changed another one let see above

Comment: some body tell this answer

Comment: you didnt answer my ques. have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: yes, I tried but didn't get out put that's why asked here.

Comment: Now  I answered to your question right, Now you should reply my question

Answer (score 2):

Ok. So your main concern about to show header with gridview. 
Simplest way to show as per your requirement is to use Recyclerview with GridLayoutManager.

```
 RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    glm.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            if (position % 4 == 0) {
                return 2;  // row with single column.
            } else {
                return 1;   // row with two column.
            }
        }

        );

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(glm);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

You will get following output.

[image]

I hope this will you.